# How to remove vertices from a graph that are not coverable by cliques?

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

Given a graph $G = (V, E)$, a set of vertices $V^* \subset V$, and an integer $k$, how do we remove vertices from $G$ such that the remaining vertices are either in $V*$ or are in a clique of size $k$ with at least one vertex in $V^*$?

Here is a toy example and solution:

The graph $G = (V, E)$ is shown below. The vertices with a white asterisk are in $V^*$. $k = 3$. The vertices that are light orange are the vertices that should be removed from $G$.

[image]

I have tried finding a clique for each vertex in $V^*$, keeping track of the vertices covered by those cliques, and then removing the vertices in the graph that are not covered by cliques.

However, finding a clique for each vertex takes a very long time when the graph is large, and I was wondering if there was a simpler way to prune out the vertices that do not belong to any cliques.

Comment: What are you asking for?  An algorithm, no matter what its running time might be?  A polynomial-time algorithm?  Polynomial in what parameters?  Is $k$ fixed or an input?   What are your requirements on the running time of any proposed algorithm?  You ask about "simpler", but the method you describe seems pretty simpler.  Do you really mean "faster"?